# Profile Application update AD

Tags: 2013, active-directory-import, user-profile-service-app

I have a "working" User Profile Service Application in that we can export information from AD to SharePoint profiles, however we have a number of fields we want to push back to AD.  I've configured these fields (department, telephone, title, jobTitle) with EXPORT connections to the relevant AD fields.

We're not seeing any udpates going back to AD and not sure what to look for in the ULS logs or MIISClient.

Any ideas how to get SP to update AD?

Additionally we've ensured the service accounts have replicating directory changes on both the domain and configuration partitions of AD.

Comment: are you running Full Synchronization in order to update the changes in User Profile Service

Comment: read the spenc harber guid, specifically last part of the blog, how to export a property to AD...http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx  things to check, 1)create proper Porperty mapping with export option 2) update the user information i,e change the telephone number 3) run ful sync.